# Does AWS Glue give an SLA on ETL job execution?

Tags: aws-glue

I'm using an hourly trigger to start an ETL job in AWS Glue but I've noticed that while the 'Run status' will show 'Running', the 'Execution time' will show zero seconds for several minutes until it finally begins moving, at which point it completes fairly quickly. I haven't found anything in the docs about delays between job invocation and execution. Is there any time guarantee that Glue gives for a job to begin executing after it is invoked?

Comment: Clearly Explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45947087/aws-glue-takes-a-long-time-to-finish

Answer (score 0):

When you start a job in AWS Glue, firt it will create the enviroment to execute the job and only then the job will start.

If you will execute the same job again, it will start just in time.